# Yahoo Mail Blocked

Tags: networking, email, yahoo-mail

Recently IT Team has upgraded system(laptop) to block yahoo Mail. I am not able to use yahoo mail during working hour in office network. But I am surprise that yahoo is not accessible when I am not in office network or not connected with office network. In brief, I am not able to access my yahoo account from home network also. Just curious how is it possible or any possibility if I can use yahoo mail from home network.
I am getting following error when I tried from my home network

https://mail.yahoo.com/ (Insecure connection firebox)

(In explorer)

This domain is blocked.

You are seeing this page because the website you have tried to access is part of an internet restricted category, or may be hosting viruses or other malicious software.  This site is blocked to protect your computer

This site was categorized in: Webmail

Admin

Comment: it's something on your laptop (system), not on company network, so changing internet connection will not make a difference. you can boot your laptop with other (live?) system. or you can update your question and provide use with some more information - operating system, application you use to access yahoo mail (web browser or some mail client?) and error you get when you try use it, please? :)

Comment: Be sure that you are not breaking any corporate policies by attempting to access Yahoo Mail on that machine. If IT has denied Yahoo Mail, it would be for some good reason that you are trying to circumvent

Comment: Agree with your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet connections on the machine are likely going through a proxy/VPN.

The proxy/VPN is likely run by the corporation you work for, and they have deemed that the use of the website is not allowed. There are several ways to get around this.

If you accept that ***you could be in violation of company policies***:

- Change the proxy settings of your browser(s)
- Disable any VPN software running in the background
- Use a web proxy, which will tunnel connections through another server
- Boot to a "live CD", which will provide an alternative OS which exists only in RAM and the CD.
- Use your own device, such as a laptop or smartphone

I would ***strongly recommend*** you talk to your IT department as to their policies. It seems likely other web mail is disabled because of data retention and/or data privacy policies.

Further more, you could potentially be facing several things by not following corporation policies:

- Disciplinary actions
- Termination of your job/contact
- A damaged reputation with other potential employers
- Revoked security credentials (if working under federal/provincial law)
- Potential legal action(s) (if working under federal/provincial law)

Comment: I agree and not going to open mail But I was curious how are they handling it